# Rubyに於いて連想配列で文字列をフォーマットする方法

Tags: ruby

以下の様なことをしたいです（`some_method`に入るメソッドを知りたい）。

```
some_method "aa/:foo/:bar/bb", {foo:1, bar:2}
> aa/1/2/bb
```

---

以下原文
Title: How to format string by hash variable on ruby?

I wan't to do it.

```
some_method "aa/:foo/:bar/bb", {foo:1, bar:2}
> aa/1/2/bb
```

Comment: ここはStackOverflowの日本語版なので、質問を[edit]して日本語に書き直して頂けませんか？もし英語で質問されたいのであれば、本家（英語版）の http://stackoverflow.com/ をご利用ください。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: @unarist さんのコメントの通り、日本語で質問するか、本家での質問をお願いします。

Comment: 短かったので翻訳をつけておきました。ただベストアンサーが選ばれることはない予感。

Answer (score 4):

ハッシュを使いたいのが主で、フォーマット指定の形式は何でもよいのなら、

```
'aa/%<foo>s/%<bar>s/bb' % {foo:1, bar: 2}
```

または

```
sprintf 'aa/%<foo>s/%<bar>s/bb', foo: 1, bar: 2
```

でよいかな。 Rubyの printf 書式仕様の一部ゆえ、数値の桁数とかも printf 同様に指定できます。

Answer (score 2):

雑に。

```
require 'mustermann'

def some_method(fmt, h)
  Mustermann.new(fmt).expand(h)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```rb
'aa/:foo/:bar/bb'.gsub(/:(\w+)/) { {foo:1, bar:2}.fetch($~[1].to_sym) }
```